# how to have dripping water when object comes out of water

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

Want to have my title come out of water, but its just completely dry, and have no drops of water in it to drip down.

I am using flip fluids, and I have a cube with hole in it comes out of water but no water drips down:

https://youtu.be/5hjTVHaEcdo

Comment: Please share a simplified file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Maybe you could experiment with having an emitter parented to the cube?

Comment: @stphnl329  I don't know how to do that, can u please paste a link of a tutorial for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: TLDR: Add another object that emits additional fluid while the object is being lifted out of the liquid.

Duplicate the cube, scale the duplicate up by a teeny bit, and change that into a liquid inflow object.

For the additional inflow object:

- Add a solidify modifier with a really small value. If the solidify value is too large, you're going to get an unrealistically thick layer of fluid.
- Delete any faces you don't want to have the fluid emitted from, notably faces such as the bottom.
- Add keyframes so that the emitter only emits for a few frames while lifting the object out of the water. You'll have to play around with how long/when you want it to do so.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, it does work, but I couldn't understand the logic behind it, how is it emitting small amount of water, is it by solidifying it or by making one emitter and the other obstacle.

Comment: I've added another object that emits additional fluid while the collision object (the cube in your case) is being lifted out of the liquid. The whole *duplicating* and *parenting* part was so that the fluid emission was a consistent thin layer on top of the object.

Comment: So the general idea is since the liquid isn't sticking properly to the object when you're raising it, add another liquid emitter that moves with the object, so that there's liquid to drip off of the object.